# Unexpected FrozenError when appending elements via <<

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash containing names and categories:

```
hash = {
  'Dog' => 'Fauna',
  'Rose' => 'Flora',
  'Cat' => 'Fauna'
}
```

and I want to reorganize it so that the names are grouped by their corresponding category:

```
{
  'Fauna' => ['Dog', 'Cat'],
  'Flora' => ['Rose']
}
```

I am adding each names via `<<`:

```
new_hash = Hash.new
hash.each do |name , category|
  if new_hash.key?(category)
    new_file[category] << name 
  else
    new_hash[category] = name
  end    
end
```

But I am being told that this operation is being performed on a frozen element:

> `<<' :  Can’t modify frozen string (FrozenError)

I suppose this is because `each` yields frozen objects. How can I restructure this code so the '.each' doesn't provide frozen variables?

Comment: Are you trying to add the value to the existing hash value for that key or make a new value for that key?

Comment: If you'tr trying to set the value then change `new_file[category] << name ` to `new_file[category] = name`

Comment: Indeed just get rid of your conditional completely if you're trying to set the value rather than add to it as both should do the same

Comment: trying to add a value to an existing hash

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want the keys concatenated as a string as a value or should the value be an array containing all strings?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add the first name to an array and then that array to the hash.

```
new_hash = Hash.new
hash.each do |name , category|
  if new_hash.key?(category)
    new_file[category] << name 
  else
    new_hash[category] = [name] # <- must be an array    
  end
end
```

Comment: If you have `new_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }`, i.e. a hash using an empty array as its default, your code becomes `hash.each { |k, v| new_hash[v] << k }`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I restructure this code so the '.each' doesn't provide frozen variables?

Short answer: you can't.

`Hash#each` doesn't "provide frozen variables".

First off, there is no such thing as a "frozen variable". Variables aren't frozen. Objects are. The distinction between variables and objects is *fundamental*, not just in Ruby but in any programming language (and in fact pretty much everywhere else, too). If I have a sticker with the name "Seamus" on it, then this sticker is not you. It is simply a label that refers to you.

Secondly, `Hash#each` doesn't provide "variables". In fact, it doesn't provide anything that is not in the hash already. It simply yields the objects that are already in the hash.

Note that, in order to avoid confusion and bugs, strings are automatically frozen when used as keys. So, you can't modify string keys. You can either make sure they are correct from the beginning, or you can create a new hash with new string keys. (You can also add the new keys to the existing hash and delete the old keys, but that is a lot of complexity for little gain.)

Comment: Uh, that's embarrassing. I should've known. I probably even did, and forgot. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for clearing up some confusion the OP seems to have. Unfortunately, your answer doesn't address the actual problem.